# How to use onBackPress in android

Tags: android

In my application I am using **`navigation drawer menu`**. I need to close this menu and get back to previous activity, when user clicks on back button.

I wrote below code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (toNightSearchView.isSearchOpen()) {
        toNightSearchView.closeSearch();
    } else if (toNightDrawerLayout.isShown()) {
        toNightDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The problem is when menu is closed app does not back to previous activity.

How can I fix this?

Comment: why don't you just start the previous activity again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use `isOpen()` to check the drawer state
if (toNightSearchView.isSearchOpen() || toNightDrawerLayout.isOpen()) { 

   //close if any of the views are open
    if (toNightSearchView.isSearchOpen()) 
       toNightSearchView.closeSearch(); 
    if (toNightDrawerLayout.isOpen()) 
       toNightDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END); 

      // Gravity.END is used for closing right drawer and start for left one
} else{ 
     super.onBackPressed(); // go back to previous activity 
}
```

or better use [isDrawerOpen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#isDrawerOpen(int))

```
if (toNightSearchView.isSearchOpen() || toNightDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) { 

    if (toNightSearchView.isSearchOpen()) 
       toNightSearchView.closeSearch(); 
    if (toNightDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) 
       toNightDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START); 
} else{ 
     super.onBackPressed(); // go back to previous activity 
}
```

Comment: When use your code, if close menu when back to activity! I want first close menu, when again back button then back activity

Comment: you want to close searchView and drawer on first backpress(if opened) and then want to exist from activity ?

Comment: yes, I want when open search or menu first close search and menu . then click again on backpress exit from activity. can you help me?

Comment: I change my code with your new update code. but not exit from activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148693/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-us-pk).